# WPF Entity Framework "invalid column name"

Tags: wpf, entity-framework

After putting 3 tables in 1 table and using migration to sync with the database, there are some errors in my project.

When I'm loading a grid, I'm getting the errors:

> Invalid column name 'RequiredDocumentId'.
>   Invalid column name 'RequiredDocumentId'.
>   Invalid column name 'OrderId1'.
>   Invalid column name 'Automatic3'.
>   Invalid column name 'Real3'.
>   Invalid column name 'FullyDivided3'.
>   Invalid column name 'Check3'.
>   Invalid column name 'SupplierDocumentNumber2'.
>   Invalid column name 'DocumentTypeId3'.
>   Invalid column name 'SupplierId2'.
>   Invalid column name 'InvoicedBy3'.
>   Invalid column name 'Automatic2'.
>   Invalid column name 'Real2'.

But these columns don't exist in the database, so where is it getting these columns?
Soemthing wrong cause of the migration? No idea..

Greets

edit:

There are 3 classes which inherit from a base class. And Entity framework created columns 3 times for the columns which are used in each 3 models.

So thats the reason why I receive columns Like FullyDivided3 and 2..

How to fix it?

Comment: You updated your edmx right?

Comment: What do you mean by "putting 3 tables in 1 table"? Show the definitions before and after.

Comment: i have same problem.